# One "layout" directory but multiple "values" directory? [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout

My aim is to support multiple screen resolutions, so came up with a solution don't know if this is recommended or not. Its not even working.

I have one layout directory, and a file in that folder that says, say

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/result_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".40"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@string/result_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@string/result_left"
    android:paddingRight="@string/result_right"
    android:paddingTop="@string/result_top" >
```

I can provide support to all resolutions by varying the padding values, so created 4 "values" directory values-ldpi, values-hdpi and so on. They all have `strings.xml` and gave proper values in strings file.

Fetches values perfectly when previewing the layout in Graphic Layout by selecting different resolution but when executing..crashes and gives an exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

line 8 being the one that says `<LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dimension values should be in a file name dimensions.xml with content like:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="padding_size">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then you reference it in your layout like this:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_size"
```

You cannot use strings because they don't convey the metric and unit information.

Answer (score 1):

Strings.xml is used for ... strings and localization, if you want to access numeric values, create a dimen.xml (the filename doesn't matter) in your values directory and enter your values like this ...

```
<dimen name="result_top">16dp</dimen>
```

Then you can access them in code with getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_top)... or in xml as you did with the strings.

Answer (score 1):

To refer a value in the resource directory use: @dimen instead of @string. also use the correct tag

```
<dimen name="key">value</dimen>
```

instead of

```
<string name="key">value</string>
```